# jsf get key/value parameters from GET request

Tags: jsf, javabeans, meta-tags, validation, query-string

in my web app I can't get the key values of query parameters with a single validator.

My webpage:

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="version" value="#{myBean.version}" 
            validator="#{myBean.inputValidator}" />
        <f:viewParam name="mobilemodel" value="#{myBean.mobileModel}" 
            validator="#{myBean.inputValidator}" />
        <f:event listener="#{myBean.preRenderViewEventHandler}"
            type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>
```

My function to validate components:

```
public void inputValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        LOG.debug("Component: " + component);
        LOG.debug("Value: " + value);
    }
```

I can't find the key value (ex. **version**) in the `UIComponent`

A solution that works fine is to have one Validator function for each query parameter. There is a way to understand the name of the parameter?

Next question: it's possible to skip all Validators and set value to myBean? I tried, but the values was not setted in `myBean.mobileModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all component attributes by [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29).

So, just this should do:

```
String name = (String) component.getAttributes().get("name");
// ...
```

Comment: thanks Balus, tomorrow i'll try it. You know why the value="#{myBean.mobileModel}" does not work if I remove validator="#{myBean.inputValidator}". The setMobileModel is not called. So I need to use the validator to set the value on my variable.

Comment: I don't recognize this problem. It works just fine for me. An SSCCE along with details about the environment would be helpful (in such way that we -and you!- can reproduce exactly the same problem by copy'n'paste'n'running it unmodified in a completely blank playground project with everything set to defaults -unless otherwise specified).